# python list.index() ValueError not IndexError

Tags: python, list, dictionary, exception, indexing

I suspect this is historical but nothing in the docs explains it.

```
demo = 'zero', 'one', 'two'
a = demo.index('three')
```

will raise a ValueError.

```
dict()['three'] and demo[100]
```

raises KeyError, IndexError

I find IndexError more logical for list.index failing. You failed to find the index of the requested key.

Am I right? And they can't change it after all this time? Or is ValueError the right one for the failing list.index

I also notice LookupError has parents: KeyError, IndexError

but not AttributeError which is effectively a keyError from **dict**

Comment: **demo** typed as tuple not dict, please check your example and update the question.

Comment: demo is a tuple. dict() is a dict. Not sure what you're warning me about

Answer (score 4):

The problem that raises ValueError here is that the value was not found in the list (or tuple, or whatever).
In your second example, the reason it's a KeyError or IndexError is because the key or index was not found in your search (in these cases you're searching for a key or index).
When running list.index(), you're searching for a value.
Thus, when it is not found, a ValueError is raised.

Comment: That does indeed justify things; meaning the answer is I'm wrong to find IndexError more logical. Thanks!